# Mori fiber space in dimension $2$ over a point is $\mathbf P^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $X$ be a surface over $k$. Let $\pi: X \to S$ be an extremal contraction. It is well-known that if $\dim(S) = 0$, then $X \cong \mathbf P^2$. I wonder if we can prove this using Mori’s result: A variety $X$ is isomorphic to the projective space if and only if $-K_X$ is ample and every non-constant morphism $\mathbf P^1 \to X$ is very free.